# Highlight empty cells to flag missing data in easiest way possible :)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a questionnaire with multiple columns where data needs to be populated by the respondent. If a cell is left blank, I want it to be highlighted to flag the respondent that they did not fill out this cell.

I have considered highlighting them all (with a pattern) at the beginning so that they become un-highlighted as they are filled. I explored some conditional formatting options, but they were also a bit confusing.

Is there a way that I can batch apply conditional formatting (to cells with data validation and formulas) to achieve this? See attached snip which shows a cell that I would want to highlight (next to the 3).

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Conditional Formatting rules to do this.

- Highlight the cells you want, and click the `Conditional Formatting` button and click `New Rule...`.
- Choose the `Format only cells that contain` option and change the dropdown to `Blanks`.
- Set your `Format...` preference and you're done!

[image: Format Blanks option screen]